# Autopopulate datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using the following code to bring up a calendar, however I am looking for this to auto populate with today's date

```
            var datepicker = new ej.calendars.DatePicker({format: 'dd/MM/yy'});
            datepicker.appendTo('#datepicker');
```

I've read some content on here and tried a few things but can't find the answer. I have tried to use .val() but that didnt work

I am somewhat of a novice and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanks but I've read that and the only thing I found regarding today's date was how to add a button but I would prefer the date to auto populate without the user having to select this field

Comment: I put wrong link, see below. I don't see where you tried that in the code you posted. https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejdatepicker#members:value
`//To set the DatePicker value during initialization  
        $("#datepicker").ejDatePicker({  value: new Date("5/5/2014") });`

Answer (score 0):

see https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejdatepicker#members:value

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
<script>
//To set the DatePicker value during initialization  
        $("#datepicker").ejDatePicker({  value: new Date("5/5/2014") });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work either unless I am doing something wrong, this is the code

var datepicker = new ej.calendars.DatePicker({ value: new Date("15/5/2020") });
          datepicker.appendTo('#datepicker');

it worked to some extent but it wouldn't let me put any date after 12/05/2020. I am missing something?